# trying to print log file on label (swift4)

Tags: ios, core-data, printing, label, swift4

My code below is calling coreData to print on a label. If I print on a label it only takes the last entry of coreData unlike what is printed on the log file.

```
for i in user! {

        print( "color: \(i.username!) Score: \(i.password!)")
        displayL.text = ( "color: \(i.username!) Score: \(i.password!)")
    }
```

LOG FILE

[image]

VIEWCONTROLLER
[image]

Comment: You are *overwriting* the contents of the label with each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @the4kman should I try a viewdidAppear of button action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in user! {
    print( "color: \(i.username!) Score: \(i.password!)")
    displayL.text = "\(displayL.text ?? "")\ncolor: \(i.username!) Score: \(i.password!)")
}
```

As you can see I'm **concatenating** the string instead of **overriding** it in every iteration

Comment: Not work getting this error String interpolation produces a debug description for an optional value; did you mean to make this explicit?

Comment: This is it  displayL.text = String("\(displayL.text ?? "")\ncolor: \(i.username!) Score: \(i.password!)"). If you could just edit your answer.